# How do you setup a custom FastCGI and PHP5 on a shared host (to use APC)?

Tags: fastcgi, php5, shared-hosting

Im not sure if I have this setup right or not =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get them to install php5-fpm, apc shouldn't be hard for them to include either.

Answer (score 0):

You usually cannot setup custom applications on a shared host.